# Search vector of struct for user inputted string

Tags: c++, vector, struct, find

I've created a program that takes in an input file with 1000+ entries formatted as such:

year, category, won, entity

I created a struct with a string element for each of parts of one entry. I now want to ask the user to input a specific entity's name such as "Emil Jannings" and return the index it is at so I can use that index to print out the line of information for that entity.

The first few lines of the input file are this:

year,category,winner,entity

1927,ACTOR,FALSE,Richard Barthelmess

1927,ACTOR,TRUE,Emil Jannings

1927,ACTRESS,FALSE,Louise Dresser

If the user inputted "Emil Jannings" as the input string, I want my loop to return the index it is at. My problem is that the loop returns 0 for i no matter what. Is there something fundamentally wrong with how my loop is set up? In addition theres a unknown amount of the same entity in the input file, Emil Jannings can show up more than once. How can I alter the loop to continue giving me every index it is found until the end of the input file? Thank you.

```
    for(;(getline(in, str)); i++){

    istringstream iss(str);
    Oscars.push_back(Oscar_Awards());

    getline(iss, str2, ',');
        Oscars.at(i).year = str2;
    getline(iss, str2, ',');
        Oscars.at(i).category = str2;
    getline(iss, str2, ',');
        Oscars.at(i).won = str2;
    getline(iss, str2, ',');
        Oscars.at(i).entity = str2;

}

cout << "Input Name of Entity" << endl;
string input;
cin >> input;



bool found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < Oscars.size(); i++){
    if(Oscars.at(i).entity.find(input)){
        cout << "Found at " << i << endl;
        found = true;
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `string::find` instead of just comparing a string with a string.
Assuming `entity` is of type `string`. The following code should work fine.

```
bool found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < Oscars.size(); i++){
    if(Oscars[i].entity == input){
        cout << "Found at " << i << '\n';
        found = true;
        break;
    }

}
```

Some points:

- [Kindly consider not using endl.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMqQOEZYVJQ)
- You don't need the safety of `vector::at` when iterating based on `i < vec.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with `if(Oscars.at(i).entity.find(input)){` : the `std::string::find` will return -1 whenever some text is not found. So `if(-1)` will be evaluated to true in the very first entry if the first entry doesn't contain the words to be searched for.

Comment: One could use `std::string::npos` instead of a literal `-1`.

Comment: Absolutely ! But I don't like giving the complete answer :) better to inspire to look up the find() method

Comment: strictly speaking the value is not `-1`, the `-1` is only used to define it. `std::string::find` returns an unsigned